colcon build fails with error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.extern.wheel'
I have completely uninstalled and extracted a previous ROS2 installation on the computer, rebooted and then installed ROS2 humble from scratch. However, the folllowing error still persists after colcon build . What should I try next?
File "/home/rosusr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/home/rosusr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 134, in setup
    ok = dist.parse_command_line()
  File "/home/rosusr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 481, in parse_command_line
    if self.handle_display_options(option_order):
  File "/home/rosusr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1120, in handle_display_options
    return _Distribution.handle_display_options(self, option_order)
  File "/home/rosusr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 684, in handle_display_options
    self.print_commands()
  File "/home/rosusr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 896, in print_commands
    cmdclass = ep.resolve()
  File "/home/rosusr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2456, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/home/rosusr/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_wheel.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ..extern.wheel.metadata import pkginfo_to_metadata
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.extern.wheel'

ROS_DISTRO=humble
OS = Ubuntu 22.04.1
Python = 3.10.2
setuptools = 58.2.0
